# php - Sonata Admin: custom view

Tags: symfony, admin, sonata-admin

I have small problem. I want to size*1024 but I dont know how. Thanks!

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('title')
        ->add('size', 'number')
    ;
}
```

I should use custom template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to your object entity a method like:

```
public function getCustomSizeValue()
{
    return $this->size * 1024;
}
```

and modify your admin `configureListFields` method by doing:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('title')
        ->add('size', 'number', array('code' => 'getCustomSizeValue')
    ;
}
```

As noticed in the documentation, you can use the `code` option to use a custom method to retrieve the value you want to be displayed.

Hope it can help you.